# How to insert table into another database using perl?

Tags: perl, dbi

---

1.I have two databases(i.e database_1m and database_current)

2.I have inserted some columns in include_status table(i.e in database_1m).I want to insert the same tables in the database_current.

3.Each database has the time field in database_1m i will get all timings but in the second database i need only the recent time rows so i used mysql query to take the recent updated time rows(i.e select * from include_status where time=(select max(time) from include_status);)

4.Here i dont konw how to use both databases in the same subroutine using perl?
code:

```
sub data
{

    $DBH = &connect or die "Cannot connect to the sql server \n";
    $DBH->do("USE database_1m;");
    $stmt = "INSERT INTO include_status(time,available,closed,used,busy,reserved,down) VALUES(\"$current_time\",\"$include{'D'}\",\"$include{'B'}\",\"$include{'A'}\",\"$include{'C'}\",\"$include{'R'}\",\"$include{'+'}\")";


            my $sth = $DBH->prepare( $stmt );
            $sth->execute() or print "Could not insert data";
    $sth->finish;
    $DBH->disconnect();




}
```

Mysql query:(to insert the recent updated rows)

```
 select * from include_status where time=(select max(time) from include_status);
```

Comment: I am little confused. Do you want to insert tables into a different database, or insert rows into a different table on the same database? I ask because you mention " i want to insert the same tables from database_1m into database_current" but the code shows `INSERT INTO include_status` which tells me include_status is a table name?

Comment: I want to insert same table into another database (i.e databse_Current).But the second database should contain only the recent updated time rows .@user2082599

Comment: the table then needs to be created if it does not exist and then you insert into table by selecting from the other table. The DBH connect is the exact same but you just add dbh2 as the connection name as dbh is already defined.

Comment: But how can i insert mysql query inside $stmt variable @user2082599

Comment: I will post an answer now.

Comment: Please do the needful@user2082599

Answer (score 1):

You want the "[INSERT ... INTO ... SELECT ...](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html)" which allows you to run a select query and insert the results directly into another table. If the two tables are in different databases on the same server, then you should be able to do it directly in one statement. Something like:

```
INSERT
INTO database_current.insert_status
SELECT *
FROM database_1m.insert_status
WHERE [some where clause]
```

And I'll just reiterate some points that I made the [last time this code was posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40254874/why-sub-routine-fails-when-connecting-multiples-databases-for-same-tables-using/40257156#40257156).

1. Please don't call subroutines using `&`. It will confuse you at some point. Please use connect() instead.
2. The fact that you don't declare `$DBH` with my makes me wonder if you have `use strict` in your code. You should always include `use strict` and `use warnings`.

Answer (score 0):

the insert will be something like this:

```
my $stmt = "INSERT 
            INTO destination_table(time,available,closed,used,busy,reserved,down)
            SELECT time,available,closed,used,busy,reserved,down from original_table";
```